# Checking documentation when creating an R package using devtools::document() , ? vs?

Tags: r, devtools

Would anyone happen to know the difference between checking the documentation for a created function when creating an R package using ? vs ?? to check.

For instance, my documentation appears after running devtools::document() in the console :

devtools::document()
Updating kfunction documentation
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Loading kfunction
Warning: The existing 'NAMESPACE' file was not generated by roxygen2, and will not be overwritten.
Writing function1.Rd
Writing function2.Rd

> ??function1()
>   ??function2()

using ?? shows "No results found" in the Help results, but ?function1 works fine.

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? I've had a bug recently where `??` doesn't return results. `??` is usually a search rather than a direct lookup, and there seems to be an RStudio bug at the moment where the search isn't working.

Comment: @Marius yes I am. That's really interesting.

Comment: Seeing this reminded me to update to the latest RStudio release, where `??` seems to be fixed.

Comment: Hadley Wickam suggests using ?, as per:
"When you use ?add, help("add"), or example("add"), R looks for an .Rd file containing \alias{"add"}. It then parses the file, converts it into HTML and displays it."
from [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html)

But I'm not sure if this is a hard rule. Thank you so much regardless Marius